# CSS Responsive Top-Bar Input

Tags: css, flexbox

I want to make top-bar
looks like google play!
*https://play.google.com/store*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdLVz.png

but i can't make flexible input box fit window size....
Div.search's min-width is 250px but not work..
help!

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.topbar{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 900px;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #C7C7C7;
}
.menu{
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 left: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 heigth: 30px;
 background-color: #777777;
}
.logo{
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 70px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #80DF5F;
}
.search{
 flex: 0 2 auto;
 position: relative;
 margin: 15px 0px 0px 200px;
 padding-right: 50px;
 min-width: 250px;
 width: 700px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: #2A77FF;
}
.search input{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
.btn{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 50px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: #FF3B3B;
}
.chat{
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 right: 20px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: #FFC536;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
 <div class="menu">=</div>
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="search">
     <input type="text">
     <div class="btn">button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add all widths of other elements (and its horizontal positions) and use `calc` to set div `.search` width:
`width: calc(100% - 380px);`

Solution for modern browsers (IE9+)

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.topbar{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 900px;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #C7C7C7;
}
.menu{
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 left: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 heigth: 30px;
 background-color: #777777;
}
.logo{
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 70px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #80DF5F;
}
.search{
 flex: 0 2 auto;
 position: relative;
 margin: 15px 0px 0px 200px;
 padding-right: 50px;
 min-width: 250px;
 width: calc(100% - 380px);
 height: 30px;
 background-color: #2A77FF;
}
.search input{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
.btn{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 50px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: #FF3B3B;
}
.chat{
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 right: 20px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: #FFC536;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
 <div class="menu">=</div>
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="search">
     <input type="text">
     <div class="btn">button</div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat">C</div>
</div>
```

Solution for old browsers (<=IE8):

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.topbar{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 min-width: 900px;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #C7C7C7;
}
.menu{
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 left: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 heigth: 30px;
 background-color: #777777;
}
.logo{
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 70px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 40px;
 background-color: #80DF5F;
}
.search-wrapper {
 min-width: 250px;
 padding-left: 200px;
 padding-right: 170px;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
 margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.search{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 padding-right: 50px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: #2A77FF;
}
.search input{
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
.btn{
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 50px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: #FF3B3B;
}
.chat{
 position: absolute;
 top: 15px;
 right: 20px;
 width: 100px;
 height: 30px;
 background-color: #FFC536;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
 <div class="menu">=</div>
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="search-wrapper">
  <div class="search">
   <input type="text">
   <div class="btn">button</div>
  </div>
 </div>
    <div class="chat">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very Interesting calc() function. I searched MDN but It's little problem... about Browser compatibility.. IE's basic support is 9. Is there another alternative that works in IE8 and earlier versions?

Comment: No problem :) Try solution that I made in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4q1ycakz/ I will edit also my entry above with that.